# How to control servlet post method with if statement?

Tags: html, servlets

I need some advice figuring out how to control my servlets post method.

Have 3 html files:

```
Create.html
Update.html
Delete.html
```

I have created a form in all of them. These forms will all call my servlets post method if used. I need to control it, so lets say if you use create.html to call it, some code should run. But maybe you want to update, and when update.html calls the servlet, it should be running some different code.

So i need help making something so i can control which scenario plays.

UPDATE:

Tried to make an hidden form, but then i can't see my create button?

my form is this:

```
     <form method="post" action="Front">

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Enter name:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="name" />
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Enter initials:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="ini" />
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Enter Cpr-nr:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="cpr-nr" />
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><br> <input type="submit" name="WhichPage" value="Create"  /> <input
                        type="reset" value="Cancel" /><br /></td>
                </tr>
```

Is this the right way to do? and then check? or should i make the hidden form + my correct form i made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put hidden fields in forms.

```
<input type="hidden" name="whichPage" value="create">

<input type="hidden" name="whichPage" value="update">

<input type="hidden" name="whichPage" value="delete">
```

Then in your servlet check the *whichPage* parameter `request.getParameter("whichPage);`